# Make a map of a map?

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, multimap

so there are 3 layers. i have map with a key, value pair where the value is another map. and second map has key,value pair where the value is just value.

so each key has another key paired with it and the second key has value.

this is what i try:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> multiMap = new HashMap<>();
```

so for example: this is data i need to put in map:

```
1 => fruit => apple 
  => color => red
  => day => friday

2 => fruit => orange
  => color => blue 
  => day => monday

3 => fruit => banana
  => color => red 
  => day => thursday
```

so if i do `Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> multiMap = new HashMap<>();`

if i want to get favorite color of 2 i want do `favColor2 = multiMap.get(2).get(color)` or something like this.

is this best way of doing this? i have problem when adding data to map.

i can not add these data. it gives error. so i try `multiMap.put(1, new HashMap<String, String>());` first and then to add "fruit" to that i try `multiMap.get(1).put(fruit, apple);` but it not work

Comment: What you are doing does work and is probably the way I would do it, though there are other ways as well. However, I voted to close this as opinion based because "is this the best way" is an inherently opinion based question.

Comment: The way you are doing it is right...best way...if its about map then I would also do it the same...

Comment: If you have a Map with a key of an incrementing integer, than you should use an ArrayList instead, in my opinion

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). If you explain what your real objective is maybe we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @nhouser9 yes sorry i add my problem to question at bottom

Comment: `put(fruit, apple);` won't work unless `fruit` and `apple` are variables. Please describe in more detail what does not work

Comment: Also, unclear why that doesn't work... http://ideone.com/iphsjc

Answer (score 4):

It depends. In the example you gave, it seems like there would always be the same keys in the second map. If this is the case, I'd suggest using an object instead to make it easier to read. A new programmer looking at the code for the first time could understand it easier this way and it's a good practice. I'd suggest a code such as the following :

```
public enum Fruit {
    APPLE, ORANGE, BANANA;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        // If needs be, override it and return a String for the fruit
    }
}
```

Do the same for the days and colors and then create the value object:

```
public class MapInfo{
    private Fruit fruit;
    private Color color;
    private Day day;

    public MapInfo(Fruit fruit, Day day, Color color){
        this.fruit = fruit;
        this.day = day;
        this.color = color;
    }

    // Create accessors here

    // Add a toString if needed
}
```

Then, your Map object would be

```
Map<Integer, MapInfo> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I mean you can always reinvent the wheel, but you could also use the MultiMap that is e.g. provided by [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap)

There you can put multiple values with the same key and modify them. It is probably a cleaner implementation than doing it all for yourself